# Can I import CSV file into MS Dynamics in a scheduled task?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, integration, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

We'd like to send few basic parameters, like name, age, gender etc.. into MS Dynamics CRM.

It should be in **Upsert** mode.

Can MS-Dynamics CRM digest file automatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamics CRM Auto Import CSV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071602/dynamics-crm-auto-import-csv)

Comment: CRM can't pull data automatically. This means that you will have to write some custom code to complete this requirement